# Dynamically update props

Tags: vue.js, quasar

As simplified below, my app has a template with a custom component.

The data is passed from Template A to custom component as props (":list")

Template A:

```
<template>
...
<custom-component     
    v-for="list in listGroup" 
    :key="list.id_list" 
    :list="list"                      
/>
</template>

<script>
    export default {        
        data() {
            return {
             listGroup: []
            };
        },
        components: {
            'custom-component':require("...").default
        }
</script>
```

The custom component

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:["list];
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Problem to solve:

A new item is added to the list sent as props.

I need the list (:list="list") to be dynamically updated so that the props in the custom component automatically reflect that update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that one way is to use a state management library(Vuex is recommended) the other is to use events.

Here is an example of using events:

create a file `event-bus.js` with the following content

```js
import Vue from "vue";
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

then in your component where you want to update `list` use this `EventBus.$emit('eventName', data);`

remember to import event-bus file

the listen to the event in the other component

```js
EventBus.$on('eventName', function (details) {
    //update list here
});
```

Comment: Thanks Confidence Yobo.  Example of using props in my custom component: <q-item-label>{{ list.name_item_list }}<q-item-label>. The data is passed by props. How do I update props = ["list"] in the custom component with EventBus?

Comment: Solved with .sync Modifier https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html?#sync-Modifier. Thanks .